# Size of Binary file change after reading in Java

Tags: java

I have a jceks (keystore file) of size 512 bytes on my application workspace. I have below java code which reads this binary jceks file and pushes the same to Bitbucket using Feign Client. When the file is pushed to the Bitbucket, the size changes to 696 bytes (using UTF-8 encoding and even with no encoding on Step 3 below). When I tried using other encodings on step 3 below (like UTF-16,UTF-16LE,UTF-BE,US-ASCII,ISO-8859_1) the size of the pushed file becomes 707 bytes, 721 bytes etc based on the the encodings. Can some one please let me know how to address this?

```
//Imports
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import java.nio.file.Files;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

//Steps

1.File f = new File(//Path of jceks file on my application workspace);

2.byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(f.getPath));

3.String toSave = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF-8);

//This String 'toSave' is what i pass to Bitbucket API which     pushes the jceks file to Bitbucket, but the size in different from actual jceks file.
```

Comment: You can't convert binary data to a string using a charset. Does the bit bucket api expect a string? Then look up the documentation to see what format the string should be. Likely it will be base64, in which case you need to base64-encode the byte array

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yes bitbucket expect a string. I used String toSave = new (Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encoded))  in step 3 and push the file to bitbucket. When i browsed the path the file in bitbucket, it is in a long string format instead of downloadable file (which was the case when i used charset). When you said base64-encode to byte array, did i do it correctly or what i did in step 3 is incorrect?